# Is there an option to set the box-shadow of QMenu?

Tags: python, pyqt5, dropshadow

I'm creating an app in PyQt5 in Python and i'm trying to customize the way the `QMenu()` looks. With setting some Window Flags and styling, I was able to make the menu look like this:

[image: Modified QMenu]

And this is my code:

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()

    app.setStyleSheet('''
        QMenu {
            background: #2b2b2b; 
            color: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #3e3e3e;                    
        }
        QMenu::item {
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 4px 25px;
            margin: 2px 5px;
        }
        QMenu::item:selected {
            background: #353535;
        }
    ''')

    menubar = QMenuBar()
    settingsmenu = QMenu(menubar)

    settingsmenu.setTitle("Settings")
    settingsmenu.setWindowFlags(settingsmenu.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    settingsmenu.setWindowFlags(settingsmenu.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.NoDropShadowWindowHint)
    settingsmenu.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    run_on_start = QAction(text="Run On Startup", checkable=True)   
    start_minimized = QAction(text="Start Minimized", checkable=True)

    settingsmenu.addAction(run_on_start)
    settingsmenu.addAction(start_minimized)

    menubar.addAction(settingsmenu.menuAction())

    win.setMenuBar(menubar)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

I got rid of the default PyQt5 box-shadow, because I think it's ugly and too harsh.

This is exactly how I want it to look, except I want it to have some sort of a shadow around it (just not the default one). Menu's from other applications all seem to have exactly the same shadow, which means that Windows itself probably applies these shadows to them as seen below:

The menu from VS Code with a subtle drop-shadow

[image: VS Code Menu]

The (tray)menu from Spotify with that same drop-shadow (A little harder to see)

[image: Spotify Menu]

And this is my menu with the default shadow (the app is called 'Playtimer')

[image: My Menu]

So my question is:
Is there a way to let Windows know that the menu needs a shadow, just not the default one.

Let me know if you need to know anything else to answer my question.

Comment: Qt doesn't draw the shadow. It just tells the OS if *it* should draw it or not. Isn't it possible that the shadow you don't like is just caused by the contrast with the lighter background the menu has?

Comment: @musicamante I added a menu to the MainWindow and to the system tray icon as well so no, the shadow looks completely different, which i think is interesting because if Windows draws it, why would my app look different from ALL the other programs?

Comment: Can you provide more appropriate screenshots for better comparison? We'd need your menu with the default shadow, and any other similar menu from another program, having a similar look to what you want to achieve *but* with a similar contrast with the background.

Comment: @musicamante I already added the one with the default shadow, which has the same contrast as the spotify one above it.